# only capitalize the first letter of the first word when it is swapped

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I am trying to only capitalize the first letter of the first word when it is swapped.

This is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ass2ID7239 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a line of text without any punctuation:");

        System.out.print("> " );

        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );

        String input = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.print("I have changed your text: ");

        input.trim();

        int firstSpace = input.indexOf(" ");

        int lastSpace = input.lastIndexOf(" ");

        String firstWord = input.substring(0, firstSpace + 1);

        String middlePhrase = input.substring(firstSpace + 1, lastSpace);

        String lastWord = input.substring(lastSpace, input.length());

        lastWord = lastWord.toUpperCase();

        System.out.println(lastWord + " " + middlePhrase + " " + firstWord);

    }

}
```

Comment: And what problem(s) do you see?  That is, how does your output (if you have any) differ from what you expected?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to stackoverflow. I've retagged your question as this has little to do with your IDE, much more with strings and (possibly) whitespace. You don't have to tell your development toolset unless it is related to the question.

Comment: When I compile then run, it capitalizes the whole first word. I only want it to capitalize the first letter of the first word that is swapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some corrections; lastWord started with a space.

```
    input = input.trim();

    int firstSpace = input.indexOf(" ");
    int lastSpace = input.lastIndexOf(" ");

    String firstWord = input.substring(0, firstSpace);
    String middlePhrase = input.substring(firstSpace + 1, lastSpace);
    String lastWord = input.substring(lastSpace + 1);

    if (!lastWord.isEmpty() {
        lastWord = lastWord.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lastWord.substring(1);
    }

    System.out.println(lastWord + " " + middlePhrase + " " + firstWord);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
input.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + input.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be lastWord instead of input?